# Logback config in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat7, logback

I'm running two web applications in a Tomcat 7.

The Tomcat has a `logback-access.xml`, which defines two appenders.

I can see that it's being picked up when starting tomcat, and the appender config is parsed correctly.

My question is, how do I let the webapp use the appenders defined in there?

I tried putting `<logger>` and `<root>` elements in the `logback-access` file, but that generates an error:

> no applicable action for [logger], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][logger]]

, and similar for `root` and `appender-ref`.

I tried putting a `logback.xml` file in my war files, both `WEB-INF/classes` and just `WEB-INF`, but it doesn't seem to be picked up.

So, how am I supposed to properly configure this?

The `logback-access.xml` in Tomcat:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/my=app.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>combined</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>localhost:5044</destination>

        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
<!-- cut specific config -->
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

The `logback.xml` in `WEB-INF/classes`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <logger name="my.package" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="com.amazonaws" level="INFO"/>
<!-- and several more loggers like this -->

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="STASH"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll just leave this here if someone has similar problems.

First of all, you don't need a `logback-access.xml` or Valve in tomcat's `server.xml` at all. Log incoming requests using filters in your app.

Then, if you need your appender(s) to be configured on the server instead of in the app, design a single `logback.xml` and put it in tomcat's `lib` folder (usually `/usr/share/java/tomcat`). You won't need a `logback.xml` in your app(s). The `logback-common` jar can be either in your war, or in the tomcat lib folder, whichever you prefer.

This way, the app will find the generic `logback.xml` on the tomcat shared classpath, and use that as if it were included in the war.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue!

Answer (score 2):

Logback-access has nothing to do with Logback in the application;

it has to be managed at Application Server level, by including the following jars ([docs](https://logback.qos.ch/access.html)):

> To use logback-access with Tomcat, after downloading the logback distribution, place the files `logback-core-1.2.3.jar` and `logback-access-1.2.3.jar` under `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib/` directory, where `$TOMCAT_HOME` is the folder where you have installed Tomcat.

and configuring it with a different syntax from Logback which doesn't include any logger:

```xml
<configuration>
  <!-- always a good activate OnConsoleStatusListener -->
  <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />  

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>access.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>access.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>combined</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</configuration>
```

Does it work ? If it work, try to change it according to your needs for the `FILE` part.

For the `STASH` part, that's a different kettle of fish, since it is LogStash - not LogBack - and other integration issues may be involved in there.

Try achieving one step at a time

Comment: That's exactly what I did. It's not working. The `logback.xml` file is there in `WEB-INF/classes`, but it's being ignored for some reason. I'd like to find out what the reason is...

Comment: Well, try posting it here, changing all the sensitive informations you need to change, if any

Comment: I've added the files. Hope that helps.

Comment: So the main difference is that I have appenders in `logback-access.xml`, not in the `logback.xml` itself. And they have to be there, because the logstash appender has server-specific config.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the logback-access part previously. I've edited the answer

Comment: Yes, I put the jars there. That part is working fine.